# Saving values updated in a python for loop using Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I'm new to Python and Pandas and I'm trying to replace all null values in an array with a specific  value.

Everytime I run this,  the updated values don't persist.

I've seen that Pandas doesn't save changes when iterating rows...so how CAN I save the changes?

Here is my code

```
animal_kinds = set(df.AnimalKind) # this gives categories used below in the "ak" like dog, cat, bird
new_color_dog = 'polka dots'
new_color_cat = 'plaid'
new_color_bird = 'stripes'

for ak in animal_kinds:
    ak_colors = ak['colors']


    ak_with_no_color = animals[(df["Kind"] == ak ) & (df["Color"] == "" ) ] 


    result_count = len(ak_with_no_color)
    if result_count:

        ak_with_no_color.at["Color"] = new_color_ak #sets new color based on kind of animal (ak) 
        print(str(ak) 'color is changed to ' + str(new_color_ak))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Avoid chained indexing

This kind of operation is known as chained indexing and it is **[explicitly discouraged in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)**:

```
df[(df['kind'] == 'dog') & (df['colour'] == '')].at['colour'] = 'black'
```

Instead, calculate and then use a Boolean mask:

```
mask = (df['kind'] == 'dog') & (df['colour'] == '')
df.loc[mask, 'colour'] = 'black'
```

#### Use a dictionary for a variable number of variables

This kind of operation does **not** work in Python:

```
new_colour_dog = 'polka dots'
new_colour+'_dog'  # want 'polka dots', but will not work
```

Use a dictionary instead:

```
new_colours = {'dog': 'polka dots', 'cat': 'plaid', 'bird': 'stripes'}
```

You can then iterate your dictionary's key-value pairs:

```
for animal, new_colour in new_colours.items():
    mask = (df['kind'] == animal) & (df['colour'] == '')
    df.loc[mask, 'colour'] = new_colour
```

You don't need to test / special-case instances when `mask` returns a series of `False` values.